# increase chances of even number

Tags: actionscript-3, math, actionscript

If I am getting a random number, how do I increase my chances of making that random number to be even. I am not looking to make it even every time. I am just looking to generate a random number say... %70 of the time or %90 of the time.

```
    private function randNum (high, low) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
    }
```

Would I pass in a greater range of numbers to this function? Or would I have to scrap this function altogether?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private function randNum (high : Number, low : Number) : int
{
    var even : Boolean = Math.random() < 0.7; //set probability of even number here
    var rand : int = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
    if (even)
        while (rand % 2 != 0)
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
    else
        while (rand % 2 != 1)
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
    return rand;
}
```

Test:

```
var even : int = 0;
var odd : int = 0;
for (var i : int = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    var a : int = randNum(1, 20);
    if (a % 2 == 0)
        even++;
    else
        odd++;
}
trace(even, odd);
```

Output:

```
[trace] 69869 30131
```

Comment: Brilliant Timofei, Thanks a lot, this is perfect.

Comment: +1, as this works, but you could end up with an infinite loop if your range doesn't contain any even numbers (or any odd numbers). Secondly, there's actually no need for a loop. For example, for numbers between 1 and 10, for odd numbers, choose rand(1,5) and return 2*n-1, and for even numbers choose rand(1,5) and return 2*n. You just need to make sure you adjust the ranges appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

A little too late ;) but another one with no loop and using bit masking operation :

`ret & -2` will make your number even, then depending on the result of `(Math.random() >= evenProbability)` you set the lower bit to be 1 to give an odd number

```
function randomRange(low:int, high:int, evenProbability:Number = 0.5):int{
     var ret:int = int( Math.random() * ( 1 + high - low ) ) + low
     return ( ret & -2 ) | int( Math.random() >= evenProbability )
}
```

Here a live test with wonderfl : http://wonderfl.net/c/9IHx